# iOS Memory management issue with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I've created a class called "**ConnectionManager**" that will handle all network request and fetch data from the server and after that call to a completion handler.

**ConnectionManager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIAlertView+CustomAlertView.h"
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>


@interface ConnectionManager : NSObject<NSURLSessionDataDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSURL *url;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSURLRequest *uploadRequest;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onCompletion)(NSData *data);
@property BOOL log;

-(void)downloadDataFromURL:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data))completionHandler;
-(void)uploadDataWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data))completionHandler;

@end
```

**ConnectionManager.m**

```
#import "ConnectionManager.h"


@implementation ConnectionManager

-(void)uploadDataWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data))completionHandler{
    // Instantiate a session configuration object.
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    // Configure Session Configuration
    [configuration setAllowsCellularAccess:YES];

    // Instantiate a session object.
    NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    // Assign request for later call
    self.uploadRequest = request;

    // Create an upload task object to perform the data uploading.
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:self.uploadRequest fromData:nil];

    // Assign completion handler
    self.onCompletion = completionHandler;

    // Inititate data
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // Resume the task.
    [task resume];

}

-(void)downloadDataFromURL:(NSURL *)url withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data))completionHandler{
    // Instantiate a session configuration object.
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    // Configure Session Configuration
    [configuration setAllowsCellularAccess:YES];

    // Instantiate a session object.
    NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    // Assign url for later call
    self.url = url;

    // Create a data task object to perform the data downloading.
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:self.url];

    // Assign completion handler
    self.onCompletion = completionHandler;

    // Inititate data
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // Resume the task.
    [task resume];
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        if (error.code == -1003 || error.code == -1009) {
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Unable to connect to the server. Please check your internet connection and try again!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"retry",nil];
                [alert showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                    if (buttonIndex==1) {
                        // Retry
                        if (self.url) {
                            NSURLSessionDataTask *retryTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:self.url];
                            [retryTask resume];
                        }else{
                            NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:self.uploadRequest fromData:nil];
                            [task resume];
                        }
                    }else{
                        self.onCompletion(nil);
                    }
                }];
            }];
        }else{
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"An unkown error occured! Please try again later, thanks for your patience." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"retry",nil];
                [alert show];
                CLS_LOG(@"Error details: %@",error);
                self.onCompletion(nil);

            }];
        }
    }
    else {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.onCompletion(self.receivedData);
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

Here is the piece of code I use to call it :

```
-(void)loadDataFromServer{
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@get_people_number?access_token=%@", global.baseURL, global.accessToken];
    URLString = [URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

    ConnectionManager *connectionManager = [[ConnectionManager alloc] init];
    [connectionManager downloadDataFromURL:url withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data) {
        if (data != nil) {
            // Convert the returned data into an array.
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *number = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            if (error != nil) {
                CLS_LOG(@"Error: %@, Response:%@",error,[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
            }
            else{
                [_mapView updateUIWithData:[number objectForKey:@"number"]];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

I figured out when using Instruments that All objects of ConnectionManager type are persistent even after getting the data from server and calling the completion handler.

[image]

I tried to change the completion handler property from copy to strong, but I got the same results. Changing it to weak cause a crash and it never be called.

Please someone guide me to the right way.

Comment: The completionHandler property should be weak and in your `loadDataFromServer` you need to hold the reference to the `ConnectionManager` in a strong property or iVar so that it isn't released when the method exits *or* (and this may be the better option) set `self.onCompletionHandler` to `nil` after you have invoked it

Comment: @Paulw11 I've tried both solutions but none of them works. Is there any way to find which property is causing the leak? Just to check whether it's the completion handler or not. At least it will help me a lot to know exactly where I should start digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I found that the URL Session object is still alive.

Based on [Apple Documentation Life Cycle of URL Session](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html) there's two cases:

1. Using the system provided delegate (by not setting a delegate), here the system will take care of invalidating the NSURLSession object.
2. Using a custom delegate. When you no longer need a session, invalidate it by calling either invalidateAndCancel (to cancel outstanding tasks) or finishTasksAndInvalidate (to allow outstanding tasks to finish before invalidating the object).

To fix the code above I only changed the delegate method "didCompleteWithError" like the following:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
if (error) {
    if (error.code == -1003 || error.code == -1009) {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Unable to connect to the server. Please check your internet connection and try again!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"retry",nil];
            [alert showWithCompletion:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                if (buttonIndex==1) {
                    // Retry
                    if (self.url) {
                        NSURLSessionDataTask *retryTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:self.url];
                        [retryTask resume];
                    }else{
                        NSURLSessionUploadTask *task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:self.uploadRequest fromData:nil];
                        [task resume];
                    }
                }else{
                    [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
                    self.onCompletion(nil);
                }
            }];
        }];
    }else{
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"An unkown error occured! Please try again later, thanks for your patience." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"retry",nil];
            [alert show];
            [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
            self.onCompletion(nil);
        }];
    }
}
else {
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];
        self.onCompletion(self.receivedData);
    }];
}
```

}